# Sonata Admin listMapper

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am using Symfony2.6 with Sonata Admin.In my Entity "Order", i have an array column named "Products". this is "ArrayCollection" type and ManyToMany relation with Product Table

How I can show this field in Sonata Admin listMapper.

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('id')
    ->add('products')
}
```

Right now in list It's showing Blank.So How I can show all Products in List Mapper in Order list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass service name for products admin in `'admin_code'` property. Result should look similar to this:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('id')
    ->add('productProperty', null, array('','admin_code' =>'application.admin.product'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for support. Right now I am trying this but not still blank :-   ->add('products', 'collection', array('template' => 'XXXBundle:Order:index.html.twig'))

Comment: Welcome. Should work just fine, you only need to change 'application.admin.product' to corresponding admin service name. You can check for it in bundles Resources/config/admin.